# How do you create categorical variables using dummy variables in r?

Tags: r

---

case1: 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0

case2: 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0

case3: 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1

I would like to get the following vectors from the table above.

answer: 2, mix, 0, 0, mix, mix, mix, 1, 2, 3

How do I solve the above problem in r?

Comment: What format is your data? Its not clear to me if you're dealing with separate vectors or a data frame.

Comment: My data is a data frame with each case as its variable name.

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `mutate(yourdf, newvar = case_when(case1 == 0 & case2 == 0 & case3 == 0 ~ "0", case1 == 1 & case2 == 0 & case3 == 0 ~ "1", case1 == 0 & case2 == 1 & case3 == 0 ~ "2", case1 == 0 & case2 == 0 & case3 == 1 ~ "3", TRUE ~ "mix"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own function to solve the above problem.

I hope it helps people who have the same problems as me.

```
dummy_to_cate <- function(mydata,column_area){
  result_vec <- NA
  vec_q=NA
  colname <- colnames(mydata)
  
  result_vec[is.na(mydata[,column_area[1]])==FALSE]<-paste(colname[1])
  for (i in column_area[-1]) {
    vec_q[is.na(mydata[,column_area[i]])==FALSE] <-1
    vec_q[is.na(mydata[,column_area[i]])==TRUE] <-0
    result_vec[vec_q==1 & is.na(mydata[,column_area[1]])==TRUE]<- paste(colname[i])
  }
   df<-is.na(mydata[,column_area])==FALSE
   result_vec[rowSums(df)>= 2]<-'mix'
  
  return(result_vec)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
sapply(asplit(rbind(c1, c2, c3), 2), function(x) {
  u <- which(x == 1)
  ifelse(length(u) == 0, 0, ifelse(length(u) == 1, u, "mix"))
})
```

which gives

```
[1] "2"   "mix" "0"   "0"   "mix" "mix" "mix" "1"   "2"   "3"
```

**Data**

```
c1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
c2 <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
c3 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply the same chr variable and NA instead of binary column?

Comment: @조지훈 Could you show an example for what you described?

Comment: For example, say the following.

c1 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "c1", "c1", "c1", "c1", NA, NA)
c2 <- c("c2", "c2", NA, NA, "c2", NA, NA, NA, "c2", NA)
c3 <- c(NA, "c3", NA, NA, NA, "c3", "c3", NA, NA, "c3")

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding
u <- which(is.na(x)== FALSE)
Thank you very much for your reply. I knew it would work if I changed it like this.